# sqlalchemy custom transformer on hybrid_property select

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I'm trying to do something slightly different from the Hybrid Attributes Doc in SQLAlchemy

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import Comparator

class GrandparentTransformer(Comparator):
    def operate(self, op, other):
        def transform(q):
            q.join(Blah).filter(Blah.type_id == Node.id, Blah.type == "Node")#some_complex_joins
            #Possibly try to add more select statements also because of the 
        return transform

Base = declarative_base()

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id =Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    parent = relationship("Node", remote_side=id)

    @hybrid_property
    def grandparent(self):
        return self

    @grandparent.comparator
    def grandparent(cls):
        return GrandparentTransformer(cls)


#sample query 
session.query(Node.grandparent).all()
```

So I'm essentially trying to catch the query with the hybrid property, and run it through a transformer when that specific Hybrid property is called; however, custom Transformer on Comparator only works on where statements (As the name implies).

Is there another way to build Transformers that catches the query (Possibly right before it runs, and modifies the query)

Thanks in advance